# Wrap span in wishlist link of header part in opencart

Tags: jquery, opencart

I want to wrap a span on wishlist link of header part in my opencart theme.

I have tried the following attempts but not succeeded any one can suggest the better way?

**THIS WORKS BUT ONLY WRAPS THE SPAN FOR A SECOND AND THEN AGAIN COMES TO IT DEFAULT STATE. A CLASS(whis) IS ADDED TO 'ADD TO WISHLIST' LINK**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.whis').click(function(){
        $("#header .links #wishlist-total").wrapInner("<span></span>");     
    });
});
```

**THIS WORKS UNTILL it is clicked on 'Add to wishlist' link of product.**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
     $("#header .links #wishlist-total").wrapInner("<span></span>");            
});
```

Comment: Why not altering the template? In default template there is a `<span>` of course... Why doing it more difficult way with JS when You could easily alter the template file (I guess `catalog/view/theme/<YOUR_THEME>/template/common/header.tpl`)?

Answer (score 1):

Try with jQuery [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function

```
$(function() {
    $(".whis").live("click", function(){
        $("#header .links #wishlist-total").wrapInner("<span/>");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but .live is also not working the span wraps but just for a second and than remains to default state again.